# I am unable to get Data into my dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I ran the SQL Query in SQL Server Management Studio and it worked.

Here is my code

```
    private void buttonRunQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (connection == null)
         {
             connection = ConnectionStateToSQLServer();
             SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);
             command = createSQLQuery(command);
             dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(command);
         }
         else
         {
             SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);
             command = createSQLQuery(command);
             dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData(command);
         }
     }

    private SqlCommand createSQLQuery(SqlCommand command)
     {
         string[] allTheseWords;
         if (textBoxAllTheseWords.Text.Length > 0)
         {
             allTheseWords = textBoxAllTheseWords.Text.Split(' ');
             string SQLQuery = "SELECT distinct [database].[dbo].[customerTable].[name], [database].[dbo].[customerTable].[dos], [database].[dbo].[customerTable].[accountID], [database].[dbo].[reportTable].[customerID], [database].[dbo].[reportTable].[accountID], [database].[dbo].[reportTable].[fullreport] FROM [database].[dbo].[reportTable], [database].[dbo].[customerTable] WHERE ";
             int i = 1;
             foreach (string word in allTheseWords)
             {
                 var name = "@word" + (i++).ToString();
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, "'%" + word "%'");
                 SQLQuery = SQLQuery + String.Format(" [database].[dbo].[reportTable].[fullreport] LIKE {0} AND ", name);
             }
             SQLQuery = SQLQuery + " [database].[dbo].[customerTable].[accountID] = [database].[dbo].[reportTable].[accountID]";
             command.CommandText = SQLQuery;
         }
         MessageBox.Show(command.CommandText.ToString());
         return command;
     }

    public DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
     {
         //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
         //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmdString, cn);
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         connection.Open();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(dt);
         connection.Close();
         return dt;
     }
```

No error is given by VS2012 and no data is presented in my DataGridView

Any suggestions?

I saw this website and it didn't really help

```
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/530616-datagridview-combobox-column-databound-item-list
```

I am using an SQL Server 2012

The updated Query brings 1 single result in the SQL Server Management Studio (which is expected). The same query does not produce any rows in my datagrid.

I can't figure out whats going on? Do I need to bind anything using the GUI for VS2012?

Comment: Is the query executing but perhaps returning 0 rows? Also, I believe you are missing a `dataGridView1.DataBind();` after you set the `dataGridView1.DataSource` property.

Comment: When I execute the query with the word "single", I get 1 row returned in the SQL Server Management Studio. In the C# app, I get nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice you're doing a LIKE search, but when you're adding your parameters, you're not using "%".  Try adding this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, "%" + word +"%");
```

Hope this helps.

BTW -- The `DataBind` method is not used in win forms for gridviews, just in web forms.

Good luck.

Comment: Nice spotted, sgeddes. Since the query contains multiple LIKEs without "%", it tries to find values which **equal** few different words at the same time, which is of course impossible.

Comment: I added the % as per @sgeddes suggestion but I am not getting any data back.

Comment: How do I get the output from my Parameterized SqlCommand? (basically I want to inspect the query to see if it's 100% valid)

Answer (score 1):

You should call method DataBind() on your DataGrid to actually bind data from the data source to the grid.

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I thought it was Web Forms. You are right, for Windows Forms you need only set DataSource. Then it is weird, that it doesn't work. Maybe your query is formed incorrectly, try setting query to static text to be the same as you use in Management Studio.

Comment: Any other suggestions @Yuriy