# How to I display the data from database from datagridview

Tags: c#

How do I display a database table (my database is sdf) to the datagridview?
Here is my code:

```
private void Show_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Contact_List";
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Co-op\Contact\Contact\ContactDataBase.sdf;Password=********");

        using (SqlCeDataAdapter adap = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, con))
        {
            DataTable dat = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dat);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dat;
        }
    }
```

The code above doesn't show any data to the datagridview. It only shows a new row with nothing in it. I am using Window Forms application.
This is the Error I get:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for
>   'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I am using window form application.                                                   i get Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: i think i remember a "using" statement(example; using System.Data.SqlServerCe) that have the word datagridview

Comment: Did you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14655139/i-am-unable-to-get-data-into-my-datagridview already?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion please try Visualize the DataTable in debug mode with breakpoints.

Make sure that data is available in DataTable

Try this sample code:

```
public void FillDataTable(string sSQL, DataTable dt)// DataTable operations 
            {
                this.cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, this.conn);
                this.dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(this.cmd);
                this.dataAdapter.Fill(dt);

            }
```

Usage:

```
        DataTable preview=new DataTable();
        FillDataTable("SELECT * FROM Contact_List", preview);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = preview;
```

Hopefully it must work .